# HTML5 Video is not reading with Angular 5 and Safari iOS

Tags: ios, angular, safari, html5-video

I have an Angular 5 app. 
I have the same video element (tiny video of 10 seconds at the server root for testing), with the same source on my route 1 and on my route 2.

I can't make things work properly.
Here's my HTML video element :

```
<video width="400" controls>
   <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Can't do easier, right ?

When I visit for the first time my webapp, on my first route loaded (either route 1 or route 2, I tried both), all caches clean, my video doesn't have cover. When I click on play :

- In the best case, the video is playing for a 2 seconds and then, the image freeze, sound is cut, the playing seeker goes at the end of video time. The end screen is green.

OR

- Most of the time, the video is not playing

If I navigate to my other route, video is not playing when I click on play. If I refresh my page, same action same result.

I tried to use a basic HTML page with just the same video tag. My video is playing as expected. At the first visit, and when I refresh. So, I assume that I don't have the byte-range requests issue.

It's working as expected in all others platforms tested (Safari/ Chrome macOS, Chrome iOS, Chrome Android).

Issue is encoutered on iPad Mini 4 with iOS 11.3.

I read a lot of things about Safari iOS issues with HTML5 video. I tried to apply several fixes without success, but anyway, posts readed don't really have the exact same problem : in their case, video wasn't playing at all.

Moreover, it's working with the same code outside Angular, so I guess it's not that problem is not about my video tag.

Comment: This issue is related to the NG Service Worker. You can find more details in the Github post  : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23447